# Use a part of macro code independently

Tags: vba, excel

I have one doubt! 
I have a code for consolidation of 22 sheets in a workbook. 
Now I want to prepare separate buttons for each sheet so that if the user wants they can consolidate only sheets required by them and not all 22 sheets.

I only know the way by creating 22 separate module having part of the codes related to each sheet. Is there any other concise way to do it which do not make me prepare 22 separate modules?

Code example:

sheets("AT").select
"whatever code that was required"

Sheets("DE").select
"whatever code that was required"

and so on.... 
Do let me know if question is not clear.

Comment: Suggestion. Make an userform with a Listbox that contains all sheets, and user selects what sheets must be consolidated. Then execute the code only in those sheets with a `For..Next` combined with a `SelecT Case...End Select`

Comment: Record a macro while adding the button. That'll give something to build on

Comment: @foxfire and burns and burns : Yes I am doing the same. I have prepared one list in excel. now I want to add buttons in front of that list so that macro code run only for that part. But I don't know where I should add for..next combined with select case... End select. Can you give an example.

Comment: Sam : Thanks for the reply sam, but recording a macro is not gonna solve my problem in this case.

Comment: It's your *consolidation code* a Sub in a module?

Comment: Yes its a sub ... Sorry I am not very clear to what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a single module. When you click a button on a sheet it will be on the activesheet. Therefore you will only need to act on the activesheet and not every sheet in the workbook.

If I was doing the job I would create a userform with a List of worksheet names that the user can select and then the module will step through each selected worksheet name in the list and do whatever actions you need. A checkbox for whole workbook action would also be useful.

Make a new Userform with a commandbutton and also a list box called "myListBox" and ensure that the MultiSelect property is set to multi and not single then add the following code. This will step through each sheet in the workbook and adds the name to the listbox. Once you select a number of names and click the command button it will print the selected names to the Immediate window

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
Dim wks As Worksheet 
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 
        Me.myListBox.AddItem wks.Name 
    Next 
End Sub 

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
    For i = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1 
        If myListBox.Selected(i) Then 
            Debug.Print myListBox.List(i)
        End If 
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks. I am very new to the vba coding world. So I don't know exactly how to execute what you are saying? Can you provide an example / illustrative code.

Comment: Make a new Userform with a commandbutton and also a list box called "myListBox" and  ensure that the MultiSelect property is set to multi and not single then add the following code. This will step through each sheet in the workbook and adds the name to the listbox. Once you select a number of names and click the command button it will print the selected names to the Immediate window.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Me.myListBox.AddItem wks.Name
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      For i = 0 To myListBox.ListCount - 1
          If myListBox.Selected(i) Then
              Debug.Print myListBox.List(i)
          End If
      Next i
End Sub

Comment: @AndyW I thinkit is much better if you edit your answer and add the code you posted in your last comment.